# Use one class NSString in another class?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, nsstring

Hi i am using one string to another class. Actually i know we have to set @property and synthsize those NSString Object. I used again it does not give value

I wrote the code like thts way:

```
/*IN One.h*/

NSString *selectionString;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *selectionString;

/*In One.m*/

tableViewDidSelect:


selctionString=[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


viewDidLoad:

selctionString=[[NSString alloc]init];





/*In Two.m*/

One *on1=[[One alloc]init];
nameLabel.text=on1.selectionString;
```

But it gives null
Here lable displays nothing why is any problems can any one help me please

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because selctionString isn't the same as selectionString. You're missing an 'e'.